# Static fields - if only one instance created from the class

Tags: c#, class, static

I have been having a hard time deciding when I should declare a class filed as static. 
I got the idea that a static field is shared among all objects created from a class, unlike a regular non-static field, which is held by each of the objects.

Then if it is known that only one object will be created from a class (because I have seen such cases many times), what is the meaning of a static field?
If the definition of "static" is "shared among all instances," does a static field serve the same role as a regular non-static field, provided there is only one object created from the class?

I got this old project from my boss to study C#, and I see some fields declared as static in a class, but there is only one object created from the class, and I am a bit confused what the point is if it does not have multiple instances.

Comment: Nothing changes. The class doesn't know that the developer intends to only create a single instance. If you know that you have a singleton class though, there is no reason to use a static field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not decide to use `static` just because there´s only one single instance. As you´ve already mentioned there *is* an instance.

The question if something should be static depends on if your member depends on an internal *state*, that is do you need to set some property befpore you can incoporate with this member. So even if there´s just one single instance existing this instance shares a set of members defining its state. Only when your member could omit all those information from that single instance it should be marked static.

However making some member `static` makes many things - e.g. mocking - quite hard as you create a heavy dependency on your class holding that member